# PHP regular expression string with + parenthesis + all non alphanumeric character with some exception as # and (?!\^)

Tags: php, regex, sms-gateway

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP remove special character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073221/php-remove-special-character-from-string)

I want to find a regex in this way:

I have the body of a SMS message in a $sms variable.
I would be have as result a string with:

```
- parenthesis
- the non alphanumeric character )([]#@*^?!|"&% and remove the other that remain
- all alphanumeric character and numeric
```

this because I have some problem with my sms gateway machine that it not deliver the  message with this character ° frequently used in Italy language to enumerate numbers.

I need to use PHP to do this, but only the regex can be a great help.

Comment: can you provide before and after examples.

Comment: So this isn't really a Question, but a request, are you trying to replace or match?, also you can post what code you have managed to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newSMS = preg_replace('/[^)(\[\]#*^?!|"&%a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $sms);
```

The regular expression is matching any one character (`[...]`) which is not (`^`) among the characters you described (`)(\[\]#*^?!|"&%a-zA-Z0-9`) and replacing them with an empty string `''`, which is essentially the same as deleting them.  This regex can be shortened to:

```
/[^)(\[\]#*^?!|"&%a-z\d]/i
```

by using `\d` to stand in for `0-9`, and case-insensitive mode (`i`) so that we don't have to repeat the letters, but the savings are minimal, especially because PHP's digits are ASCII only anyway.