# Remove special HTML characters from string in PHP

Tags: php, html, hash

I found many results but for some reason nothing works for me! I've tried `preg_replace` with regex and also `html_entity_decode`, but no good...

I want to select words that has a hash mark prefix e.g. `#WORD`, which works just fine, but sometimes the hash mark is read as `&rlm;#WORD` and it misses up.

Example: 
`This is a normal #hash_mark but ‏#this_isn't`

as it appears:
[image]

The regex I use to select words with hash mark prefix `'~(?<=\s|^)#[^\s#]++~um'`

---

In the question marked as a duplicate, the answer doesn't work for Unicode text, as seen in the image:[image]

---

The code does remove all special characters including Unicode text, what's required is only to replace the `&rlm;#` with a normal `#`

```
function remove_special_char($sentence){    
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s','',$sentence);                  
}

echo remove_special_char("hello مرحبا привет שלום");
```

Output:

```
hello
```

Comment: Well... your regex matches hashes *preceded by a space*. That hash is not preceded by a space. Should it be? Should your regex match something else?

Comment: You could add the right-to-left marker to your positive lookback assertion, such as: `'~(?<=\s|^|&rlm;)#[^\s#]++~um'`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis the solution is the same, but the problem which he met was rather difficult to recognized by naked eyes. Because these characters were rendered same visual.

Comment: If it "doesn't" work could you explain more? Include what you've done and the _actual_ text that it doesn't work on; not pictures. The site supports unicode so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

There was two different characters [special_characters](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/special_characters/) 
[image]

Let you look exactly what happened I've made some debug

```
        var_dump(ord('‏#')); //return ASCII value of this char
        $str1 = 'This is character 226 ‏#';

        $str1v1 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $str1);

        var_dump(ord('#')); //return ASCII value of second char
        $str2 = "This is character 35 #";

        $str2v1 = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $str2);


        var_dump($str1v1);
        var_dump($str2v1);

        var_dump($str1);
        var_dump($str2);
```

Output:

```
int 226
int 35
string 'This is character 226 ' (length=22)
string 'This is character 35 ' (length=21)
string 'This is character 226 â€#' (length=26)
string 'This is character 35 #' (length=22)
```

Maybe you or your end user have done to copy and paste somewhere and they included the converted charcode like what you described `(&rlm;#)`. Since they are rendered the same surface and make you confused.

To escape from those characters, I have used the regex in following line

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $str1);
```

The regex has been taken from [PHP remove special character from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073221/php-remove-special-character-from-string)

Comment: There may be some slight confusion here. The UTF-8 encoding of the right-to-left marker (U+200F) is the 3 bytes `0xE2 0x80 0x8F`. Because of PHP's lack of internal unicode handling, the standard string functions act upon bytes, rather than characters. The ord() function returns the value of the first byte in the string supplied as its parameter - which in this case is 226.

Comment: Good to know it. I did not know exactly the reason which you gave here. Thanks

Comment: Very useful information, but it seems that the regex by the end does only work on non-Unicode characters, on the other case it messes up all the characters.