# Remove special characters in string

Tags: php, html, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I am currently doing this:

```
$a = 'some string with special characters';
$a = htmlentities($a);
$a = trim(preg_replace('/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i', '', $a));
```

This works but I am wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What's your definition of special and why do you need to remove them?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I am scraping an HTML page, it contains certain characters like `Â` and I want to remove those.

Comment: Look here for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073221/php-remove-special-character-from-string

Comment: @HenkdeJager That is quite the same to what I'm already doing.

Comment: For the mere sake of destroying the page content?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I'm only getting specific data, e.g., `Â data_i_need Â`

Answer (score 2):

> it contains certain characters like Â and I want to remove those.

Try `utf8_decode`, or more feature-filled:

```
$output = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $input);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/iconv)

The reason I bring this up is because what you are seeing are encoding issues, *not* "special characters".

Comment: Do you happen to know how to apply that in `phpQuery`? More specifically, I am using `phpQuery::newDocumentFile` to scrape an HTML page.

Comment: I couldn't remember the name of the function, but this is what I was going to suggest. Converting the "special characters" to their similar counterpart wouldn't destroy the original text as much.

Comment: Nope. No idea. But if there's any kind of encoding setting somewhere then you should set that to UTF-8 (instead of using the code in this answer - because this code is somewhat destructive)

Comment: The OP clearly states that he wants to completely wipe out "special" characters (whatever that means), not decode them properly or convert to his application's encoding. Yet you have my +1 because I simply can't believe him :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Pfft, had me worried there!