# Change characters like ä

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having problems with converting a string like `Präsentation.pdf` to `Prasentation.pdf`.

I've tried everything with the php function iconv() but the encoding is already UTF-8.

How could I make sure all these strings are correct with no 'illegal characters'?

Comment: add in ur html <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073221/php-remove-special-character-from-string