# How to remove the special tag from string

Tags: php

I have a string like

"Ger&#228;umiges Studentenapartment in Aachens Fu&#223;g&#228;ngerzone am Aquis Plaza!"

I want to remove the special character form the string.
i have already used strip_tags and htmlspecialchars for this. but did not work.

Comment: those html entities look like letter characters. the first and last one are [A, umlaut](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=latin) so you might want to make sure you want to really remove these outright or just convert them to a regular character

Comment: Just convert them to regular character.

Comment: There are no ***tags*** in this string to be removed. What exactly are you expecting the end-result to be here?

Comment: I think You people are not reading the question before downgrade the question. Have you really cant understand what i mean. I need this function in php "html_entity_decode". Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP remove special character from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073221/php-remove-special-character-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` to remove these special characters.

For example:

```
$output=preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7f)]*/s','',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

Usage:

```
echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');
```

output:

> abcdef-g

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)